# Как добавить событие по изменению чекбокса?

Tags: vue.js

ВОпрос, мне надо при наличии нажатого чекбокса, присвоить переменой status, значение true.
Как это сделать? Так же любопытно послушать мб кто-то посоветует в целом подобную задачку по другому реализовать.
Суть в том, что человек пишет возраст, если ему до 18 - закрывается доступ всплывает окно "сопровождающий" чекбокс. Нужно что бы по нажатию галочки - статус становился true(доступ открывается). Если человеку больше 18 - доступ открыт.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Проверка возраста</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <section id="app">
                <h1 id="message" v-bind:class="[ status ? 'open' : 'close']">{{ result }}</h1>
                <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Ваш возраст" id="age" v-model="age">
                <button type="submit" id="button-check" v-on:click="checkAge">Проверить</button>
                <div v-show="hide" id="hide-param">
                    <label>Есть сопровождающий? <input type="checkbox" name="accompanied" id="accompanied" v-model="checked" v-on:click="accompanied"></label>
                </div>
            </section>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>

    let app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:{
                message:{
                    open: 'Вам 18 лет и больше, доступ открыт',
                    close: 'Вы младше 18 лет, доступ закрыт',
                    unclose: 'Вам меньше 18 лет, но есть сопровождающий, доступ открыт'
                },
                age: null,
                result: null,
                hide: false,
                status: null,
                checked: null
            },
            methods: {
                checkAge(){
                    this.checked = false;
                    if(this.age < 18){
                        this.result = this.message.close;
                        this.status = false;
                        this.hide = true;
                    }else{
                        this.status = true;
                        this.result = this.message.open;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У checkBox можно поставить обработчик v-on:change="yourFunc()". Соответственно в самой функции производить необходимые изменения. Либо поставить whatch на изменение переменной, прописанной в v-model и прописать алгоритм в handler. На мой взгляд второй вариант более читабельный.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739358/vuejs-checkbox-update - v-on:change
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html - watch